# The need for branches in Git

Tags: git

I have been using Git for a while, and I am wondering if the construct of "branches" in Git is really necessary.

The Git branch can be thought of as a pointer to a specific commit. Here is one workflow:
1. `git checkout master` //on master branch
2. Develop
3. `git checkout -b newFeature`
4. `git commit -a -m "shiny new feature done!"`
5. `git checkout master`
6. `git merge newFeature` //fast-forward
7. `git branch -d newFeature`

Such a straightforward task involved 7 steps. Of course, the creation of the `newFeature` branch is probably unnecessary - we could have just worked on master itself. But if we eliminate the concept of branches, steps 5 to 7 would be unnecessary.

Getting rid of branches would also save us from the "detached HEAD" state, and the warning that is displayed every time a commit that is not associated with a branch is checked out.

Branches may be necessary for some other VCSs. But why does Git need branching? Can't one do everything, and with added efficiency, if one just use and refer to commits? Every Git commit already has one or more pointer(s) that record its parental relationship(s).

Comment: Have you yet learned the git commands such as `clone`, `fetch`, `push`? What would happen if everyone were working on master?

Comment: @JoshLee Thank you for reading my question. I cannot immediately see the scenario you have in mind, however. Would you provide more specifics please?

Comment: Good luck in remembering tens or even hundreds of commit hashes.

Comment: @taskinoor Won't you just need to remember the hash for each branch? Are you saying there are hundreds of branches?

Comment: @flow2k over time there might well be many branches. And the hash changes on every single new commit. It would be utterly impracticable. I would suggest working with git for a few minutes, it would make the topic completely clear, immediately.

Answer (score 7):

You are correct that branch names are merely a convenience.  Getting rid of them would not save us from "detached HEAD" though: it would mean that we *always* have a "detached HEAD".  (This has far-reaching implications, because references—including branch names—also *retain* commits.  But we can imagine a system where this is not true, such as that in Mercurial.)

Note that in *any* commit-based version control system, we have the notion of a *current commit*.  That's the commit we have extracted from the VCS into our work-tree, so that we can use it or work on it.  Since the true name of each Git commit is an apparently random hash ID like `deadc0ffee` or `feedbeef` or whatever, we will have to note "interesting" hash IDs down somewhere.  The *most* interesting one is, of course, the *current* one; so we note that down, writing a hash ID into something we can access using the name `@` or `HEAD`.

That's a *detached HEAD* in Git-as-it-is.  It would just be "the head", which is always detached (so that we don't need the adjective "detached" at all), in your proposed setup.

Now, of course, we need to allow *distributed* development.  While I may work on my copy of things, Alice and Bob have their own copies, and do their own work.  They have *their* current commits, which may be different, especially as they add new commits.

Suppose Alice has finished up the new widget feature and Bob has documented the frammitz.  I now go to pick up their work (by whatever means), so I get some commit(s) from Alice that I never had before.  I need to know their hash IDs—at the least, I need the ID of her newest commit, which has her earlier commit hashes.  I pick up Bob's documentation commit(s) that I never had before, and need his IDs too, or at least one of them.

I'd better attach a name to each of these two commit IDs, lest I forget whether `badcafe` is Alice's or Bob's.  Perhaps I could use `alice/master` as the name for `badcafe`.  Hm, wait, I think I have just invented the *remote-tracking branch name*.

---

There *are* other ways to organize all of this.  For instance, Mercurial uses permanent, global branch names, and allows anonymous *heads*<sup>1</sup> within each branch.  It turns out that these permanent, global branch names have their own issues, so instead, Mercurial users often use lightweight names called *bookmarks* to track anonymous heads.  These bookmarks are, as it turns out, direct analogues to Git's branch pointers: names for commit-IDs.

In the end, we find that we *want* these things.  Git's history, and (in my opinion) poor nomenclature—which has too many similar-sounding words that mean different things—make it a rough ride to get used to Git's words for the things, but the things themselves are quite desirable.

---

<sup>1</sup>These heads are similar in some ways to Git's HEAD, but different in others.  Once they have attached bookmarks, though, they are *extremely* similar to Git's branches.

Comment: Thanks torek for this detailed explanation. Yes, it's valuable to have the same pointer (e.g. `alice\master`) point to ever-changing commits. Why do you say branches names retain commits? In Git, the branch name just points to *one* commit, and to access other commits, it would need the parent pointer in the commit, itself, right?

Comment: This is somewhat of an implementation detail, but Git uses a *garbage collection* system to dispose of old, unwanted objects (including commits, though there are four types of objects in all: annotated-tag, commit, tree, and blob). Git encourages operations that make temporary objects (such as temporary blobs for `git rerere`, temporary commits for interactive rebase with squash operations, and so on) and allows you to transplant commits, stripping out the originals in a deferred manner, with `git rebase`. To make this all work, [continued]

Comment: [con'td] To make this all work, Git uses the notion of *external references*, kept outside the repository graph, to mark objects as "live" or "in use". Periodically (`git gc --auto`), Git scans the *entire* graph—this is a very slow operation, done in the background—and *prunes*, as they all it, any *unreachable* object. Hence to delete now-superfluous commits, you simply (and quickly) delete the external reference. If no other object or external reference refers to this commit, this commit is now *unprotected:* `git gc --auto` will eventually remove it.

Comment: Mercurial uses a different technique: unwanted objects must be "stripped" at the time you are done with them (e.g., during transplanting or modifying commits with `hg rebase` or `hg histedit`). To facilitate recovery, instead of delaying the garbage collection (Git's system for this is quite fancy), Mercurial packages stripped objects into a "bundle" and writes the bundle into a side store. (It turns out that "undo a rebase" is a common need, so we need these saved bundles.) This makes doing these things in Mercurial significantly slower than it is in Git.

Answer (score 2):

"Branch" has two meanings in git. Trivially, it is just a temporary and otherwise irrelevant name/alias we give to a commit so we do not have to remember the hash. This has obvious benefits, working directly with commit hashes is very awkward and usually reserved for special occasions. Theoretically, we could work without these, but it would be very cumbersome indeed.

The other meaning, of "branch" is the phenomenon that a commit can have more than one child commit. This is the real "meat" of a branch. Funnily, this meaning is not actually represented in any technical/physical way in git beyond the fact that a commit had more than one child.

This latter act of branching, and conversely merging, is what makes the git commits a directed acyclic graph DAG. And *this* is absolutely, totally crucial for git, it is the magic behind it. Other systems, for example Subversion, had nothing like it, so it is definitely worthy of mention.

For more in depth information on it, check out the git book at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2, especially its chapter on branching and merging, and on internal data structures.

Comment: AnoE Which Git book are you referring to?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2 , @freshair